# Multilingual management of multimedia content in Mysql Schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, multilingual

Well, 
i have the Assets: Images, Videos, Sounds, Texts
each Asset is multilingual and i also want each one of them to relate to other Assets in my database whats the best schema to model these relationships in my database schema?

So far i have:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is hidden in these three:

Single Table Inheritance

Class Table Inheritance

Concrete Table Inheritance

described at

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/30/how-to-model-inheritance-in-databases.aspx